# 'react-native-barcodescanner' reading only QRCodes

Tags: android, npm, react-native

I am using  module'react-native-barcodescanner' to read bar codes but only QR-Code can be scaned by the android mobile.  How to read all kind of barcodes in a ract-native applicaion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library working fine , only we need to scan barcodes on landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Bacode Format at the build statement one by one,

Below are the supported formats

```
    BarcodeFormat.UPC_A
    BarcodeFormat.UPC_E
    BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
    BarcodeFormat.EAN_8
    BarcodeFormat.RSS_14
    BarcodeFormat.CODE_39
    BarcodeFormat.CODE_93
    BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
    BarcodeFormat.ITF
    BarcodeFormat.CODABAR
    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX
    BarcodeFormat.PDF_417
```

like the below example

```
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
  .setApplication(getApplication())
  .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
  .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
  .setFormats(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A)
  .setFormats(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13)
  .setFormats(BarcodeFormat.CODE_93)
  .setFormats(BarcodeFormat.CODE_128) 
  .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
  .addPackage(new RNCameraViewPackage())              // <------ add here
  .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
  .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
  .build();
```

Comment: could you please guide more ? which file  ?

Comment: At the scanning activity

The Main Java Class of the used Library